# jQuery closest() after siblings return 0

Tags: jquery

How can I check to make sure the siblings don't contain the class I am looking for before I start traveling up the DOM with `closest()`? I could do it with the `closest()` and `siblings()` functions but I am wondering if there is a jquery function that already exists that would take care of this.

Comment: Could you provide some html to make your questions clearer?

Comment: The [closest docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) say it does return the current element - i.e. the sibling - if appropriate, which sounds like that's what you want. What's wrong with just calling closest()? Does it give you the wrong result?

Comment: The question's not THAT unclear. "make sure the siblings of a given element don't contain..." would've been clearer, but code sample wouldn't help THAT much.

Comment: @Rup Closest docs say : Begins with the current element. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector, The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element

Comment: @Greg Pettit - Thank you. My thoughts too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`closest()` looks up the DOM, `siblings()` looks to either side; I don't believe there's any jQuery method that does both. You'll have to start with `siblings()` (possibly with `.andSelf()`) and then test the `length` to see if you need to check `closest()` instead.

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid since I thought there was a more elegant way of doing this. But I think your answer is probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Add the class as a selector to `.siblings()`. Then, check whether the size of the selection equals zero.

```
if($(this).siblings('.aRandomClass').length == 0) {
    // No sibling with class aRandomClass
} else {
    // The length is not zero, so there's a sibling with class aRandomClass
}
```